# Can I populate a pd.dataframe with keys that match a value that's already in the dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter-notebook

I have a dictionary
`my_dict={'google':'googletotcom',"kroger":"krogerdotcom","ucla":"unidotcom","IG":"picturedotcom","walmart":"walmartdotcom", "fb':"fbdotcom","ucla":"unidotcom" }`

and a dataframe

```
dataframe=pd.DataFrame({'NAMES' : ['google', 'fb', 'ucla','ikea', 'wiki'], 'LINKS' : ["","","","",""]})
```

```
NAMES     Link  
google           
fb                   
ucla           
ikea
wiki                          
IG
```

I want to populate the dataframe so that it checks if the key of the dictionary matches a value in the dataframe, then populate that specific link to the value of its key. As you can see, some values included in the dataframe are not in the dictionary and vice-versa.

I have tried this:

```py
for key,value in my_dict.items():
    if key in craft:
        CraftBeverage["Website"]=dict1[key]
```

but it populated the links colum with the last link in the dictionary.

But I want to have something like this:

```
NAMES      Link  
google     googletotcom      
fb         fbdotcom          
ucla       unidotcom    
ikea
wiki                          
IG         picturedotcom
```

Comment: Why don't you make a dataframe from the dictionary and use `merge` ?

Comment: craft is a variable I named for the"NAMES" column and CraftBeverage["Website"] is my actual file name so just ignore that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `map` function, which will map the keys' values as a series given a column of keys:

`dataframe['LINKS'] = dataframe["NAMES"].map(my_dict)`

output:

```
    NAMES               LINKS
0  google        googletotcom
1      fb            fbdotcom
2    ucla           unidotcom
3    ikea                 NaN
4    wiki                 NaN
```

Comment: Good to know, if it worked will you please select it as an answer by clicking the checkmark under the votes for future visitors of the question? Thanks!